# Entity Framework 6 DbUpdateConcurrencyException When Adding New Rows To Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Here's my problem: Every time I attempt to add a row to the database, I get this exception:
**DbUpdateConcurrencyException**

No one else uses this development database except me. Please help. I'm at my wits end here.

Here's the code:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
    context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

    var newProduct = new ProductsEntity { ProductTypeId = 1 };
    context.Products.Add(newProduct);

    // The line below always throws the exception
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The context, **MyDbContext** is defined as follows:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductsMap());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ProductsEntity> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The **ProductsMap** and **ProductEntity** are defined as follows:

```
public class ProductsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductsEntity>
{
    HasKey(t => t.ProductId);

    ToTable("Products");

    Property(t => t.ProductId)
        .HasColumnName("ProductId")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    Property(t => t.ProductTypeId)
        .HasColumnName("ProductTypeId");

    // Stored Procedure Mapping
    MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
        s.Insert((i => i.HasName("InsertProduct")
            .Parameter(p => p.ProductTypeId, "ProductTypeId")
            .Result(r => r.ProductId, "ProductId")
            )));
}

public class ProductsEntity
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The stored procedure, **InsertProduct** is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct]    

@ProductTypeId int,  
@Identity int = NULL OUTPUT  

AS  
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products]  
    ( [ProductTypeId] ) 
    VALUES 
    ( @ProductTypeId  )    

END    

SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

RETURN
```

And, the table **Products** is defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
    ProductId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ProductTypeId int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    ProductId ASC
) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) 
ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Products WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY(ProductTypeId)
REFERENCES dbo.ProductTypes (ProductTypeId)

GO
```

What appears to be happening, if it helps, is that the identity seed of the **Products** table is in fact getting incremented every time the code hits the **SaveChanges()** line below. I can tell, because when I test running **InsertProduct** in SQL Server Studio, the **ProductId** column skips one integer for every attempt I make at running this code.

My best guess is that Entity Framework executes the **InsertProduct** procedure, but somehow the transaction is blocked and gets rolled back. I have no idea though, honestly.

Here's the console's Debug output contents:

```
Opened connection at 10/25/2016 5:53:43 PM -07:00

Started transaction at 10/25/2016 5:53:43 PM -07:00

[dbo].[InsertProduct]


-- ProductTypeId: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 10/25/2016 5:53:44 PM -07:00

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2016-10-26T00:53:44.0238952Z","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"CTWlUsYMEbU=","ai.device.roleInstance":"MyComputerName.Domain","ai.operation.name":"POST deal","ai.operation.id":"CTWlUsYMEbU=","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf: 2.1.0.363"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"SERVERNAME| DevDatabase | [dbo].[InsertProduct]","id":"JDD838YyJkc=","value":16.0379,"dependencyKind":0,"success":true,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
-- Completed in 28 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 10/25/2016 5:53:44 PM -07:00

Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in EntityFramework.dll
```

Here's the text from the inner exception:

> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

And, it's true, no rows are inserted. And again, no one else uses this development database; I'm the only one with dbo rights.

***EDIT: FOUND A SOLUTION***

Ok, big thanks to @Juan below for pointing me in the right direction. The issue was indeed that EF needed some way of knowing what happened to the primary key, but it was pretty subtle.

The first thing I did was try changing the stored procedure above like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct]    

@ProductTypeId int,  
@Identity int = NULL OUTPUT  

AS  
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products]  
    ( [ProductTypeId] ) 
    VALUES 
    ( @ProductTypeId  )    

END    

SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() // <-- Added this line

RETURN
```

Then, what happened was that the exception thrown changed to **DbUpdateException** (from **DbUpdateConcurrencyException**). Additionally, the inner exception text now read as follows:

> A function mapping specifies a result column 'ProductId' that the result set does not contain.

Well, this tipped me off that I was making progress. So the next thing I tried was altering the Fluent API in **ProductsMap** as below:

```
public class ProductsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductsEntity>
{
    HasKey(t => t.ProductId);

    ToTable("Products");

    Property(t => t.ProductId)
        .HasColumnName("ProductId")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    Property(t => t.ProductTypeId)
        .HasColumnName("ProductTypeId");

    // Stored Procedure Mapping
    // ------------------------
    // Changed the "ProductId" below to "Identity", since that is
    // the name of the output variable in the stored procedure
    MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
        s.Insert((i => i.HasName("InsertProduct")
            .Parameter(p => p.ProductTypeId, "ProductTypeId")
            .Result(r => r.ProductId, "Identity")
            )));
}
```

This change above threw the same **DbUpdateException**, but the inner exception text changed to this:

> A function mapping specifies a result column 'Identity' that the result set does not contain.

At this point I noticed that the tool-tip for the .Result() method in Fluent API reads as follows (emphasis added by me):

> Configures a column of the result for this stored procedure to map to a property. *This is used for database generated columns*.

So, that got me thinking that the .Result() method in Fluent API probably isn't for SQL stored procedure output at all. I tried to look up the documentation on EF6 for how this method is supposed to work, but I couldn't find anything useful. And, I couldn't find *any* examples of it using a SQL stored procedure output, which is telling.

So instead, that got my attention on my only database generated column, which is this one:

```
    Property(t => t.ProductId)
        .HasColumnName("ProductId")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

With this in mind I changed my stored procedure above as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProduct]    

@ProductTypeId int,  
@Identity int = NULL OUTPUT  

AS  
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products]  
    ( [ProductTypeId] ) 
    VALUES 
    ( @ProductTypeId  )    

END    

SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
// Altered the line below a little bit
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

RETURN
```

And, again, I got this resulting **DbUpdateException**, :

> A function mapping specifies a result column 'Identity' that the result set does not contain.

So, then I figured, I should just change the .Result() method in Fluent API back to what I had before, and perhaps everything would work out:

```
    // Stored Procedure Mapping
    // ------------------------
    // Changed the "Identity" back to "ProductId"
    MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
        s.Insert((i => i.HasName("InsertProduct")
            .Parameter(p => p.ProductTypeId, "ProductTypeId")
            .Result(r => r.ProductId, "ProductId")
            )));
```

And guess what? That worked!

For good measure, I also tried removing the .Result() specification entirely, like this:

```
    // Stored Procedure Mapping
    // ------------------------
    // No more .Result() specification
    MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
        s.Insert((i => i.HasName("InsertProduct")
            .Parameter(p => p.ProductTypeId, "ProductTypeId")
            )));
```

And, interestingly, this also worked just fine as well!

So, ultimately, my conclusion is that specifying a column as database generated in Fluent API is probably redundant with the specification of the .Result() method under **MapToStoredProcedures()**. I couldn't find anything in the EF6 documentation to better explain this, but at least now I can solve the problem.

Thanks again to @Juan for the big helpful finger pointing me in the right direction! : )

Comment: I am sorry but... why go through the trouble of mapping the insert to a stored procedure? Why not just let EF do what EF does? That being said, there is usually more error information accompanying this exception. Please post.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 1) We cannot grant insert permission on production databases. We can only granted execute permission to specific stored procedures, hence the mapping is required. Also, you can generally get better performance with many inserts (i.e. 1000s) if you map to a stored procedure. EF can be slow to write out that many inserts. 2) What other error information would help? The inner exception maybe?

Comment: I can understand the permissions. Always a pain. There are ways to improve performance on EF inserts. The bottlenecks with lots of records are usually due to multiple calls to SaveChanges() or accumulation of unchanged objects within the context. I have seen some nice extensions out there too for bulk insert. There is usually an error message that comes along with this exception. It may be the message of the exception itself or in the inner exceptions. Gather all the info you can and post so we can help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It won't solve my annoying permissions issues, but I'll have to look into those bulk insert extensions; that's great advice. I agree that there should be as few calls as possible to SaveChanges(); that's also excellent advice. Additionally, I posted the text from the inner exception above at the very bottom. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think I may know what the problem is.

The EF is not detecting the insert. I think this is because you have an OUTPUT parameter called @Identity but I don't see that being mapped back anywhere:

```
// Stored Procedure Mapping
MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
    s.Insert((i => i.HasName("InsertProduct")
        .Parameter(p => p.ProductTypeId, "ProductTypeId")
        .Result(r => r.ProductId, "ProductId")
        )));
```

Either you map the @Identity parameter to the ProductId field or you have your SP return the identity to let the EF know the insert succeeded:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: This was almost the right answer! Very close. I'll edit my post above to reflect what worked. Thank you again so much for the advice!

Comment: Awesome. I am glad I was able to help you.